# Jetty 9: How to run a specific webapp on HTTPS only

Tags: https, jetty

my question can be reduced to: how do I set up Jetty 9 through config xml files so that I can have one app on port X and another on port Y? The latest documentation that I can find on the net isn't very clear.

Thanks
Renault

Answer (score 0):

In your `WEB-INF/web.xml` for the webapp that is supposed to use SSL.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Force SSL</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This assumes you have SSL on the server (connectors) setup and configured properly.

Comment: When you say "SSL on the server (connectors) setup and configured properly", are you referring to the Jetty server/connectors setup? If true, that is what I was referring to initially. I'm not sure how to set that up. But your answer above helps